# Показать только нужные блоки при нажатии кнопки. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.
Есть такая проблема, к сожалению не могу сам решить...
Есть ряд кнопок(это кнопки контрактов к примеру), при нажатии на одну из них появляется блок с опциями этого контракта.
Каждая кнопка должна иметь свои опции(они могут повторятся, но не всегда)
К примеру при нажатии на 
Selectionner -> появляются только опции 1,3,4,5
Selectionner2 -> появляются только опции 1,2,6 и тд.
Можно отображать по классу или по id не имеет значения...

```
<button class="btn btn-success">Selectionner</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">Selectionner2</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">Selectionner3</button>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="1">
           <!-- option content -->                                
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="2">
           <!-- option  content -->                                
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="2">
           <!-- option  content -->                                
     </div>
 </div>
```

Буду рад помощи. Спасибо

Comment: Ну, в целом Вам же ничего не мешает на кнопку повесить что-то по типу: `id="1_3_4_5"`. Дальше получать `id` нажатой кнопки, бить `id` по спец.знаку ( " _ " в примере), и показывать блоки, у которых `id` совпадают с элементами получившегося массива. Хотя конечно немного индийское решение...

Comment: Вполне интересно,вот  только я не знаю как сделать 
- "бить id по спец.знаку ( " _ " в примере)"

Comment: [.split](https://javascript.ru/string/split) Вам в помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, так, опции, которые нужно показать при клике на данную кнопку указываем в data атрибуте через запятую, потом при клике на кнопку берем ее дата атрибут, разбиваем по запятой и возвращаем массивом, потом уже перебираем этот массив и показываем элементы, у которых id соответствует значению из массива, остальные скрываем.

```js
(function ($) {
  
  var options = [];
  
  $(document).on('click', '.show-options', function(){
    
    $('.options').hide();
    
    options = $(this).data('options').split(',');
        
    options.forEach(function(value){
      $('#'+value).show(); 
    });
    
    return false;

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.options{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-options="1,3,4,5" class="btn btn-success show-options">Selectionner</button>
<button data-options="1,2,6" class="btn btn-success show-options">Selectionner2</button>
<button data-options="3,5,6" class="btn btn-success show-options">Selectionner3</button>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="1">
           1                   
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="2">
           2               
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="3">
           3                     
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="4">
           4                       
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="5">
           5                          
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="6">
           6                     
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function show_options(options){
   $('.options').hide();
   for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++){
       $('#'+options[i]).show();
   }
}
```

Используем эту функцию в каждой кнопке с указанием id опций, которые должны быть отображены

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="show_options([1,3,4])">Selectionner</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="show_options([2,3,6])">Selectionner2</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="show_options([1,2])">Selectionner3</button>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="1">
           <!-- option content -->                                
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="2">
           <!-- option  content -->                                
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 options" id="3">
           <!-- option  content -->                                
     </div>
 </div>
```